# Power Automate - Document Generation

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, powerapp, document-template

I have a requirement to rebuild a Nintex workflow in Power Automate.  This flow is about Document Generation.  It’s fairly straight forward in Nintex, but not so much in Power Automate without a Premium license.  So I need to build this with a standard Power Automate account.

Here’s what I have.  Modern SharePoint Library (`DocTemplateLibrary`) contains a Word document where I’ve added Quick Parts to certain sections utilizing `Site Content Types` and `Site Columns`.  I also have a `PowerApps` form connected to another SP List.

So I want three fields that get populated in the Form to populate the Quick Parts I added to the Template.  These fields are `Requestor Name`, `Dollar Value`, and `Date`. I have everything set up in the List, Library, PowerApps, and in the Template itself.  But I have no clue what actions I should use to :

- Generate the Template from the Library,
- Populate that Template’s three fields with submitted Data from the PowerApps form, then add that new Document to a new Library (Documents to Review).

I know it’s pretty straight forward with a Premium license, but I’m not authorized to utilize it.  So I have to build this flow with a standard license.

Does anyone know the right way I should approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HyacOSm-6k

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately in this video, the developer is using a Premium Connector.  I don't have access to any premium connector.